# R, obtain pointed column value from another table (faster)

Tags: r, pointers, dataframe

I have two data frame. One with all the data A, and a smaller one B that contain an unique identifier of A and column names of A. I am trying to add a column on A base on what the B is pointed to. In another word, I need to get data from A pointed by B. 
For example

```
A<-airquality
B<-data.frame(Month=unique(A$Month),col=c("Ozone","Solar.R", "Wind", "wind","Solar.R"))
```

This would give me the following

```
> head(A)
   Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
> B
            Month        col 
1               5       Ozone
2               6     Solar.R
3               7        Wind
4               8        wind
5               9     Solar.R
```

The result should be something like

```
> head(A)
   Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day  ADDED
1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1    41
2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2    36
3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3    12
4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4    18
5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5    NA
6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6    28

> tail(A)
    Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day ADDED
148    14      20 16.6   63     9  25    20
149    30     193  6.9   70     9  26   193
150    NA     145 13.2   77     9  27   145
151    14     191 14.3   75     9  28   191
152    18     131  8.0   76     9  29   131
153    20     223 11.5   68     9  30   223
```

The only way I can do it is

```
 for(i in 1:nrow(B))
{ 
  j<-A$Month==B$Month[i]
  k<-subset(A, select=B$col[i])[j,]
  A$ADDED[j]<-k
}
```

while this does work, it become extremely slow as I have a big dataset. I feel like I am doing it the dumb way. What is a good way of doing this? 
Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with the `sapply` or `lapply`-functions.

```
ADDED <- sapply(1:nrow(B), function(i){
  A[A$Month==B$Month[i], (B$col[i])]
})
A$ADDED <- unlist(ADDED)
```

For partial matching, you would have to filter the data, to get only rows where B has values and then assign the values. But befor we have to assign a value for all rows of the ADDED column; in this case NA.

```
A$ADDED = NA
A[A$Month %in% B$Month,]$ADDED <- unlist(ADDED)
```

That is already talking only a 1/3 of the time, compared to a for-loop.

```
appl <- function(){
  ADDED <- sapply(1:nrow(B), function(i){
    A[A$Month==B$Month[i], (B$col[i])]
  })
  A$ADDED1 <- unlist(ADDED)
}

lappl <- function(){
  ADDED <- lapply(1:nrow(B), function(i){
    A[A$Month==B$Month[i], (B$col[i])]
  })
  A$ADDED1 <- unlist(ADDED)
}

forlo <- function(){
  for(i in 1:nrow(B)) { 
    j<-A$Month==B$Month[i]
    k<-subset(A, select=B$col[i])[j,]
    A$ADDED[j]<-k
  }
}


library(microbenchmark)
mc <- microbenchmark(times = 1000,
  sapply = appl(),
  lapply = lappl(),
  forloop = forlo()
)

mc
```

> ```
> Unit: microseconds
>     expr     min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval cld
>   sapply 337.478  359.2125  378.6964  369.7775  385.474 2324.913  1000  a 
>   lapply 319.367  340.7990  366.8448  349.2510  362.532 9051.828  1000  a 
>  forloop 964.136 1013.6415 1074.5584 1032.5070 1059.825 5116.802  1000   b
> ```

Comment: what if B was not a complete list of unique identifier. Let's say B<-B[1:3,]

Comment: I edited my answer to include partial matching. But I am sure that you could do that even faster with `data.table` and some merging.